# always vs cleanup condition in post section of Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

In the post section we have `always` and `cleanup` as Conditions (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post)

When running the pipeline I saw that commands in `always` and `cleanup` were executing despite of Pipeline and stage's status.

So, what is the difference between those two options?

Comment: From the docs, `cleanup` run the steps **after every other** post condition. So, both `always` and `cleanup` are executed every time, but `cleanup` as the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

always - Run the steps in the post section regardless of the completion status of the Pipeline’s or stage’s run.

cleanup - Run the steps in this post condition **after every other post condition** has been evaluated, regardless of the Pipeline or stage’s status.

order of execution should be:

```
always
changed
fixed
regression
aborted
success
unsuccessful
unstable
failure
notBuilt
cleanup
```